# Self killing Perl script

Tags: perl

I need a way to have a perl script to find its own pid and kill itself using the system command. In code:

```
my $pid = &getScriptPID();
system("taskkill $pid");
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: `taskkill` is a Windows program no?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pid of the current process is available via the `$$` variable.

The better question is why you can't just use the `exit()` function...

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't seem to be working. I think I might have to redownload perl.

Answer (score 5):

[`kill`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/kill.html)`KILL =>`[`$$`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%24)`;`

But why? Why not just [`exit`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html) or [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html)?

Comment: Note that `kill`, `$$`, `exit` and `die` are hyperlinks to their respective docs. They're not just blue because of syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the `pid` with the variables `$PID` or `$$` from within your script.

See `perldoc perlvar`